# Поиск слова в строке и вывод строки содержащей слово

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Пишу программу с графическим интерфейсом,которая в файле (файл с названием  книги/автор/год выпуска) будет находить строку по одному или из нескольких ключей и выводить каждую строку в которой есть такой ключ.
Написала только оболочку.Вывод сделала того,что ввожу. (в идеале,вывод бы сделать того,что нашло по ключам.
Принцип программы, должна искать по автору и/или год написания и/или названию книги. Пишу,на Python 3.4
Пыталась добавить в код программы такой код:

```
i=0
with open('D:/test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        i=i+1
        if word in line:
            print(line, end='')
            break
```

Выбивает в лучшем случае,только общее кол-во строк файла.Если слова нет,то ошибку.
Подскажите,каким образом можно совершить поиск слов и вывод определенной строки?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, код с отступами (что пытаетесь добавить) и текстом (который на изображении); к тому же, как я понимаю, проблема не связана с кодом на изображении, т.е. он, возможно, не нужен

Comment: http://prntscr.com/klzjkw     Так же пробую с данным кодом сейчас. Пишет ошибку "if name in i:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not StringVar"

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у Вас `name` - содержит не строку (а некую StringVar), что неправильно

Comment: Изменила код,ошибки теперь нет.Но выводит одну и ту же последнюю строку из файла,какие бы ключи я не вносила. Возможно можно по-другому код записать для поиска слова в строке и выводе строки?

Comment: О `Windows Vista` круто! Моя любимая ОСь!

Answer (score 1):

```
i=0
with open('D:/test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        list_words = line.split()
        i=i+1
        if word in list_words:
            print(line, end='')
            break
```

Будет найдено первое вхождения слова в файле. Затем break.